# Is Windows crashing on running Android Emulator after latest Windows updates?

Tags: android, android-emulator

My Windows 10 system recently got updated with Windows Update patches (KB4549949 & KB4549947) (11/05/2020) . Since then, whenever I start Android Studio (I have stable 3.6 no canary build ), my system hangs and then crashes after some time. Is anybody else also facing this problem ? Is there a workaround ? This is a office laptop and the system is managed by IT I am not allowed to uninstall the updates.

Answer (score 0):

Removing HyperV from Windows Features solves this issue. I see this issue being reported in some other forums also.